# Flutter. Future should wait for callback

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I am implementing Huawei push notifications in Flutter.
Here: https://pub.dev/packages/huawei_push/example

I'd like to be able to have a way of calling this:

`String? token = await PushNotificationsService().getPushNotificationsToken();`

from my code and have my own class `PushNotificationService()` fetch the token and return it.

My problem is that for Huawei I need to implement some listeners inside `PushNotificationsService()` class.

```
void _onTokenEvent(String event) {
    _token = event;
    showResult("TokenEvent", _token);
  }

  void _onTokenError(Object error) {
    PlatformException e = error as PlatformException;
    showResult("TokenErrorEvent", e.message!);
  }

...

Push.getTokenStream.listen(_onTokenEvent, onError: _onTokenError);
```

But how should I setup my `getPushNotificationsToken()` ? I need to return a future inside it, but how to handle that `Future` so that it's only "triggered" once one of my two listener callbacks are called ?!

I'm sure it's a basic solution, but I'm new to Flutter unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Flutter Push Kit plug-in can obtain token information only through event listening.